# Embedded PNG: 1034 Type Coercion Failed

Tags: actionscript-3

Every single tutorial says to do it like this, which used to work:

```
[Embed(source="/../images/MyImage.png",mimeType="image/png",smoothing="true")]
private static var ImageClass:Class;

//[...]

var bitmap:Bitmap = new ImageClass();
```

Again, this used to work, but now (when I use PNGs) it gives me `Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert MyImage_png$3e9131867d9df437bb131fa0f25e1d80-479819629@c756f89 to flash.display.Bitmap.`

Note that this method also fails:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new ImageClass());
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do you embed a PNG as a Bitmap? The PNG has transparency, if that matters.

Comment: var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new ImageClass()); would never work anyway.

Comment: @BotMaster , I know; one of the other regulars here answered that images are embedded as BitmapData and that was the correct way to do it, although he deleted his answer after I indicated it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, finally figured it out. The image is no longer a Bitmap if you enable smoothing in the embed tag. This works:

```
[Embed(source="/../images/MyImage.png",mimeType="image/png")] //NO SMOOTHING
private static var ImageClass:Class;

//[...]
var bitmap:Bitmap = new ImageClass();
```

Comment: I think you can add smoothing after instantiating a `Bitmap` out of this class to the instance, so that you can use both smoothed and non-smoothed versions of a bitmap from a single data source (in fact, if you would need more than one bitmap of this and don't plan to alter those bitmaps, it's better to have one `BitmapData` instance of `ImageClass` and then create bitmaps referring to that instance.